# yum dependency resolution not working

Tags: linux, centos, centos7, yum

I've got a chef recipe to bootstrap some worker nodes that I've been using for quite some time, and for the first time in a while I needed to increase the size of my worker pool, but found that the new nodes were not bootstrapping properly due to the yum error:

```
Error: Package: cyrus-sasl-md5-2.1.26-21.el7.x86_64 (abc-os)
           Requires: cyrus-sasl-lib(x86-64) = 2.1.26-21.el7
           Installed: cyrus-sasl-lib-2.1.26-20.el7_2.x86_64 (@abc-os)
               cyrus-sasl-lib(x86-64) = 2.1.26-20.el7_2
```

Where `abc-os` is our internal repo so we can lock down package versions. Naturally I assumed that this was the problem, but on checking into the repo I found that the complete set of packages for both `21.el7` *and* `20.el7_2` are present.

Furthermore running `yum list available cyrus-sasl-md5` gives:

```
cyrus-sasl-md5.i686       2.1.26-20.el7_2    abc-os
cyrus-sasl-md5.x86_64     2.1.26-21.el7      abc-os
```

And querying the repo's sqlite file in `/var/cache/yum/x86_64/7/abc-os/gen` returns:

```
sqlite> SELECT name, arch, version, epoch, release FROM packages WHERE name LIKE 'cyrus%' ORDER BY arch, version, epoch, release, name;
cyrus-sasl-lib  i686        2.1.26      0           17.el7
cyrus-sasl-lib  i686        2.1.26      0           20.el7_2
cyrus-sasl-md5  i686        2.1.26      0           20.el7_2
cyrus-sasl-pla  i686        2.1.26      0           20.el7_2
cyrus-sasl      x86_64      2.1.26      0           17.el7
cyrus-sasl-dev  x86_64      2.1.26      0           17.el7
cyrus-sasl-lib  x86_64      2.1.26      0           17.el7
cyrus-sasl      x86_64      2.1.26      0           20.el7_2
cyrus-sasl-dev  x86_64      2.1.26      0           20.el7_2
cyrus-sasl-lib  x86_64      2.1.26      0           20.el7_2
cyrus-sasl-md5  x86_64      2.1.26      0           20.el7_2
cyrus-sasl-pla  x86_64      2.1.26      0           20.el7_2
cyrus-sasl      x86_64      2.1.26      0           21.el7
cyrus-sasl-dev  x86_64      2.1.26      0           21.el7
cyrus-sasl-lib  x86_64      2.1.26      0           21.el7
cyrus-sasl-md5  x86_64      2.1.26      0           21.el7
cyrus-sasl-pla  x86_64      2.1.26      0           21.el7
```

At the moment I'm stumped as to why this is happening, and what to do to dig into this further.

For reference, the OS is CentOS 7.2 x86_64.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem turned out to be that someone had configured the [yum version lock](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/98873) configuration for only `cyrus-sasl-lib` but none of the other cyrus packages, which is what seems to have caused yum to be unable to resolve the versions correctly.

Probably the best option would be to add in the other packages with matching versions, but since these particular packages are of little consequence to the current incarnation of this platform I just removed `cyrus-sasl-lib` from the version lock altogether. Now yum installs/upgrades everything to latest and the instances bootstrap themselves without issue again.

Answer (score 0):

cyrus-sasl-md5-2.1.26-21.el7.x86_64 requires cyrus-sasl-lib to be on the version 2.1.26-21 but you have another version (2.1.26-20).

I think you should uninstall cyrus-sasl-lib and reinstall with the good version.